# What are some workflows that one engineer may use to implement a software specification?

Tags: requirements, specifications, user-story, implementations

I've never implemented an entire specification before and wanted to know what a workflow may look like to do so. I have worked on code that was backed by such a specification, but only in maintenance have I had to refer to the spec, and only very small portions of it.

This would probably be an awful first thing to implement, but let's use as an example [OpenPGP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4880#section-3.1).

How might a software engineer tackle such a feat? Some things I could think of but am not certain about:

1. Read the whole specification "cover-to-cover", taking notes on key details
2. Read through it and cut myself a bunch of "issues"/tickets for each major feature and work through them

In addition, please include some references to smaller example specifications that could be useful to try, if known.

Comment: There is not n one answer. A complete spec for an airliner control system is going to have different demands than Facebook for Cats

Comment: I don't think 1. and 2. are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @whatisname must it only be a question that demands one answer? This is also why I said "some" workflows.

Answer (score 1):

Drink coffee and repeat ad infinitum. :)

### Try it!

Actually, I think the best way for you to answer your own question would be to try it.

It's not unusual in SE or CompSci classes in universities to give similar assignments to students. Instead of asking them to implement a toy project with an overly simple spec, it's sometimes more interesting to ask them to replicate a real-time system:

- implement a FTP client and/or server (see [RFC959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959.txt)),
- implement an IRC client and/or server (see [RFC1459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459.txt) and [RFC2812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812.txt)),
- implement an HTTP server (see [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)),
- implement a web browser,
- etc...

Thankfully these all have RFCs documenting them, or other more or less standard specs. I remember having a bunch of these on my bed-side table for a number of months when I needed to work on them.

In the case of client-server apps, it's quite handy as well as it means you can work on one side of the problem and rely on existing software to test your solution.

I remember the FTP and IRC specs where digestible enough. Implementing the [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) was a bit of a head-banger...

It's also a nice approach, as there often are other RFCs that later supersede the original ones, and so you can both see how the design evolved over time, and how new features needed to be added on top of the existing designs.

The same thing can apply for language specs.

(I wish more modern specs for popular frameworks and technology would still be written in the same format as RFCs... They were an exercise in transcribing complex details in plain but clear text form.)

### Okay, but, ahem... How about that workflow?

To answer your question, I'd say to:

1. Read the spec cover to cover.
2. Take a bunch of notes as you go.
3. Build from the ground up: Personally I'd focus on sections of the spec that could be implemented as strictly independent parts first, and that I could easily unit test. Then work up the architecture this way.

Answer (score 1):

Personally i favore small iterations.

Therefore i would read the whole spec to get an overview of what will come. Its nice to know because then some of my design decisions can already take into account what i will have to implement later.
BUT: In real life projects the requirements are changing. Therefore i would not try to focus on considering EVERYTHING that will come into detail. I would try to make it possible to add those features later, but i would not prepare a detailed interface to it.
Or to say it differently "Big design up front" (designing everything before the first code is written) never worked in any of my projectes, nor in a project i have heard of. Design in steps. Even if you think you know all that needs to be known about the requirements.

Thats said up front, i would then take one requirement after the other and implement it.
Yes, one result is, that i write code for requirement A and later i have to refactor it to allow the requirement B. But thats okay.

Just make sure that you CAN change the existing code with confidence. That means write a lot of testcases (TDD is cool for that), encapsulate, ensure that errors cant propagate through the system, and so on and so on.

That would be my approach